# CSS checked is not working with html <ul> element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, translate, checked

I'm trying to animate an ul element up and down with checked, but it's not working, I'm not sure if it's related to the translateY animation or to the ul element.
I already tried using "+" instead of "~" but I'm still having the same issue.

```css
.events{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Verdana;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transform: translateY(120%);
 top: 120px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.events li {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 width: 319px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.swipe-container {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

#swipe-up {
 display: none;
}

.icon-swipe {
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Oswald light;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#swipe-up:checked ~ .events{
 transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
  <div id="events-wrapper">
    <div class="swipe-container">
     <input type="checkbox" id="swipe-up">
     <label class="icon-swipe" for="swipe-up">eventos</label>
    </div>
    <nav class="events">
     <li><a href="">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: This checkbox hack is not good practice, and you should use a tiny bit of JavaScript instead to provide better accessibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend using an actual `<ul>` for the list (.events), it is now a navigational html tag `<nav>`. ;)

When you use the following code:

```
#swipe-up:checked ~ .events{
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

The browser expects it to be in the same parent, but in your example it isn't. I've edited it a little to make it work with only CSS. If you want your old structure you can resort to JavaScript to show/hide your list.

```css
.events{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Verdana;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transform: translateY(120%);
 top: 120px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.events li {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 width: 319px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.swipe-container {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

#swipe-up {
 display: none;
}

.icon-swipe {
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Oswald light;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#swipe-up:checked ~ .events{
 transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="events-wrapper">
    <div class="swipe-container">
     <input type="checkbox" id="swipe-up">
          <label class="icon-swipe" for="swipe-up">eventos</label>

          <ul class="events">
            <li><a href="">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">4</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update - JavaScript (preferred)**

For a JavaScript solution you could use the example below. As you can see we can also clean up the HTML structure a bit to keep it more simple.

I also set the class on the body, this gives you more flexibility if you want other elements to react to this event.

```js
(function() {
  // Get element which will react to the click, can be anything.
  const element = document.querySelector('.js-showEvents');
  // Added class to the body after a click on the element.
  const classActive = "events-is-active";
  // Just getting the body.
  const body = document.body;

  // Before we do anything to the element, check if it exists.
  if (element != null) {
    // Add a event that 'listens' to a click on a given element, in this case '.js-showEvents'.
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      // Set a variable to check if the events are already 'active'
      const isOpen = body.classList.contains(`${classActive}`);

      // If events is not clicked yet, add class to the body.
      if (!isOpen) {
        body.classList.add(`${classActive}`);
      } else {
        // If events has already been clicked, remove class from body.
        body.classList.remove(`${classActive}`);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log(`Given element does not exist.`);
  }
})();
```

```css
.events {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateY(120%);
  top: 120px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.events-is-active .events {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.events li {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 319px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.swipe-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.events-title {
  font-family: Oswald light;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="events-wrapper">
  <div class="swipe-container">
    <!-- 
      Added 'js-showEvents' as a JS 'hook', to seperate functional classes and styling classes. This class can only be used once on a page, since I used 'querySelector' in this example to keep it simple.
    -->
    <h1 class="events-title js-showEvents">eventos</h1>

    <ul class="events">
      <li><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I was making tests with nav instead of ul and I forgot to change it.

Comment: Also I got another little doubt, I already fixed this but i want to optimize the code, you recommend me to use js if I want to keep the structure, is it possible to keep that structure with sass too?

Comment: Hi @AlexDis, with the structure I meant your HTML structure. Do you mean you would like an example in JavaScript? If you do, I don't mind writing one.

Comment: Hi @AlexDis, I've added a JavaScript solution and added extra comments to what does what. I've wrapped it in a function `(function() { //code })();` in case you've got to use it with other JS libraries.